# Atualizar página ao voltar de outra página ionic/angular

Tags: ionic

bom-dia pessoal, estou tendo um problema ao inserir/editar/deletar dados no db, tenho uma página clientes que lista os nomes, os botões que fazem uso das funções que citei levam para um novo componente add-clientes, após inserir/editar/excluir algum dado volta para a página clientes usando router.navigate(), porem os dados não são atualizados, gostaria de recarregar o conteúdo da página ao voltar de outra tela, o ngOnInit só carrega na primeira vez que acesso a página, dai é como se ela estivesse sempre ativa.

Só gostaria de saber como faço para atualizar o conteúdo da página clientes sempre que eu voltar da outra página que uso para add/edit/del ;/

Agradeço desde já :)

**clientes.page**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.clientes = [];
    this.start = 0;
    this.carregar();
  }


carregar() {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      let dados = {
        requisisao: 'getdata',
        limit : this.limit,
        start : this.start
      };
      this.service.inserirApi(dados, 'inserirCliente.php').subscribe(data => {
        for(let cliente of data['result']){
          this.clientes.push(cliente);          
        }
        resolve(true);
      });
    });
  }


 addClient() {
    this.router.navigate(['/add-cliente']);
  }

  editar(id, nome, telefone, email, mode) {
    this.router.navigate(['add-cliente/', { id, nome, telefone, email, mode }]);
  }

  excluir(id, nome, telefone, email, mode) {    
    this.router.navigate(['add-cliente/', { id, nome, telefone, email, mode }]);

  }
```

**add-cliente.page**

```
cadastrar() {

    this.msg = "Dados inseridos com sucesso.";

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      let dados = {
        requisisao: 'add',
        nome: this.nome,
        email: this.email,
        telefone: this.telefone
      };
      this.service.inserirApi(dados, 'inserirCliente.php')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.router.navigate(['/clientes']);
        this.msgOk();
      });
    });
  }

  addEditar() {

    this.msg = "Dados alterados com sucesso.";

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      let dados = {
        requisisao: 'edit',
        nome: this.nome,
        email: this.email,
        telefone: this.telefone,
        id: this.id
      };
      this.service.inserirApi(dados, 'inserirCliente.php')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.router.navigate(['/clientes',{ rec:1 }]);
        this.msgOk();
        console.log(this.id);
      });
    });
  }

  addDelete() {

    this.msg = "Dados deletados com sucesso.";

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      let dados = {
        requisisao: 'delete',
        id: this.id
      };
      this.service.inserirApi(dados, 'inserirCliente.php')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.router.navigate(['/clientes']);
        this.msgOk();
      });
    });
  }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ola @Hyroshima, não altere a pergunta para indicar que você encontrou uma resposta. O melhor a fazer nesse caso e publicar uma resposta, após 48 horas o sistema vai liberar para você aceitar sua própria resposta, você ainda pode [ver sua alteração aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/429020/2). -- [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução**

Após verificar o ciclo de vida da página percebi usar o ngOnInit era inviável pois como era uma página que necessitava de atualização sempre que algum evento acontecesse, então apenas removi a chamada da função carregar assim como as variáveis lá e as aloquei em **ionViewWillEnter** ficando-o asism:

```
 ngOnInit() {}

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.clientes = [];
    this.start = 0;
    this.carregar();    
  }
```